# While looping through Object HTMLDivElement, applying ChileNode style zindex giving undefined in firefox and chroome?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
function setPosition(currentdiv) 
{
    try {
        for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementById("parentContainer").childNodes.length; i++)
        {
           document.getElementById("parentContainer").childNodes[i].style.zIndex = 0;                       
        }

        currentdiv.style.zIndex = 1;
    } catch (e) {
        alert(e.Message);
    }
}
```

I am passing Html Div Element in function setPosition and itterating through its child nodes and setting z-index property to zero. Its working fine in IE but giving Undefined in very first itteration in firefox and chroome. Any help ?

Comment: I suspect that you are trying to set the zindex of textnodes.. see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154801/childnodes-not-working-in-firefox-and-chrome-but-working-in-ie

Comment: @Henrik yes there are textnodes too in DivElement but I am unable to handle it too.

Comment: textnodes inherit their style from their parent, I'm quite sure that they would return 'undefined' if you try to get their "style" attribute, as it is undefined.. 
see http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_nodetype.asp for more information on nodetypes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what I was trying to tell you in the comment was, that the nodetype textnode simply doesn't have a style attribute, and that IE ignores textnode, when giving you the childnodes..  This should work..

```
function setPosition(currentdiv) 
{
    try {
        for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementById("parentContainer").childNodes.length; i++)
        {
               var elem = document.getElementById("parentContainer").childNodes[i]
               if(elem.nodeType != 3){
                    elem.style.zIndex = 0; 
               }                      
        }

        currentdiv.style.zIndex = 1;
    } catch (e) {
        alert(e.Message);
    }
}
```